Discretization of the heat equation: is the bilinear form $a(u,v) = (u,v)_{L^2} - \tau (u',v')_{L^2}$ coercive for every $\tau > 0$?
I'm working on the heat equation in 1D on the domain $\Omega = (0,1)$
$$ \partial_t u(t,x) - \partial_x^2 u(t,x) = 0 $$
with boundary conditions $u(t,0) = u(t,1) = 0$ and initial temperature distribution $u(0,x) = u_0(x)$. We can semi-discretize the problem by replacing the time derivative with a backwards difference quotient
$$ \partial_\tau^- y_i = \frac{1}{\tau} (y_i - y_{i-1}) $$
which yields the ordinary differential equation
$$ \frac{1}{\tau} (y - u_0) - y'' = 0$$
for the first step. If $u_0 \in C(\Omega)$, one can show that there exists a unique solution $y \in C^2(\Omega)$ of this ODE.

I'm interested in the weak formulation of this semi-discretization: find $y \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$ \left(\frac{1}{\tau} (y - u_0),\varphi\right)_{L^2} - \left(y',\varphi'\right)_{L^2} = 0 \quad \text{for all } \varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega). $$
The interesting question is: is there a unique weak solution?
We can try to apply the Lax-Milgram theorem. Rewriting the problem gives
$$ a(y,\varphi) := (y,\varphi)_{L^2} - \tau (y',\varphi')_{L^2} = \tau (u_0, \varphi)_{L^2 }$$
If $\tau > 1$, we can get coerciveness of the bilinear form $a$ by applying the Poincaré inequality (with $c=1$ on the domain $\Omega = (0,1)$), yielding
$$ |a(v,v)| \geq (\tau - 1) \lVert v' \rVert_{L^2}. $$
But the aim of the discretization is $\tau \to 0$, so this is not a very satisfactory result.
Is the bilinear form $a(u,v) = (u,v)_{L^2} - \tau (u',v')_{L^2}$ coercive for every $\tau > 0$?

Why do you want to semi-discretize ? Is it necessary in your case study, like wanted ? or can't you just work with the original equation and transforming it into variational formulation ?

I'm giving a talk about the heat equation in the context of gradient flows. The goal of the semi-discretization is to show $\mathcal E(y_i) \leq \mathcal E(y_{i-1})$, for the Dirichlet energy $\mathcal E$ as a discrete energy inequality. Showing uniqueness of the weak formulation would be enough for that.

OK i see  thx   for precisions

The weak formulation and associated bilinear form is missing a minus, coming from partial integration. It should be:
$$ \left(\frac{1}{\tau}(y-u_0),\varphi\right)_{L^2} + (y',\varphi')_{L^2} = 0 \quad \text{for all } \varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$$
and
$$ a(u,v) = (u,v)_{L^2} + \tau (u',v')_{L^2}. $$
This bilinear form is coercive.

The original bilinear form is not coercive for all $\tau$. Take for example $\tau = \frac{1}{10}$ and the function $$v(x) = x(x-1).$$
Then $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and
$$ \lVert v \rVert_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{30}, \quad \lVert v' \rVert_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{3}, $$
therefore
$$ a(v,v) = \frac{1}{30} - \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = 0.$$
Then for all $c>0$
$$ \lvert a(v,v) \rvert = 0 < c \cdot \lVert v \rVert_{H^1},$$
so $a$ cannot be coercive. There should be similar counter-examples for other $\tau \in (0,1)$.
